# Inconsistent sendkey with batch file

Tags: batch-file, arduino

I'mt trying to create a batch file that wil be called by another program but can not get the sendkey to work properly.  It calls Zune and opens it but does not send the ctrl+p to start the play.  If I have Zune open and run the batch file repetitively it will eventually start playing but I may have to run the batch 10 time in a row.  Not sure why that is. Ideas?

```
@echo off
setlocal

start zune.exe 
call :SendCtrlP "Name in Windowtitle"


:SendCtrlP <app>
setlocal
set vbs=%Temp%\_.vbs
>%vbs% echo set s = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
>>%vbs% echo s.appactivate "%~1"
>>%vbs% echo s.sendkeys "^p"
cscript //nologo %vbs%
if exist %vbs% del /f /q %vbs%
exit /b
```

Comment: As it appears, the `Ctrl + P` is probably getting sent to Zune before it has instantiated the playback control message stack, so the keys are discarded.  Try adding a delay between the start of Zune and the sending of keys. `ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 2000 >nul` (2 second delay example)

Comment: That seems to have done it!  Thank you.  I have tried to do the same with the sleep function but with no success.  Any idea why sleep wouldn't get the same results.

Comment: `sleep` most likely did not work because there is no native Windows command or utility (except for [Windows 2003](http://ss64.com/nt/sleep.html)) for sleep.  There is a [`timeout`](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) utility as of Windows 7 (or manually added to XP).  Otherwise, if you do have a sleep tool it has to be 3rd party.  The `ping` method is used as a common batch delay due to being backwards compatible with most versions of Windows.